# coxph function gave a weird hazard ratio in my simulation case

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I fit three Cox models. The three hazard ratios are 0.52, 1.02, and 0.514, respectively. The first hazard ratio is the hazard ratio between the treatment arm and the control arm. The second is the hazard ratio between the control arm and the external control arm. Here, 1.02 means the control arm is worse than the external control arm. The third hazard ratio is the hazard ratio when we pool the control arm and external control arm together. Since the control arm is worse than the external control arm, after we pool both these treatments together, the third hazard ratio should be larger than the first one. However, coxph function gave a counterintuitive answer. Dose anyone know the reason? Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: The title of your post needs fixing. `coxph` in the R `survival` package is more than 30 years old and is one of the most carefully validated functions in all of statistical computing, thanks to Terry Therneau.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sorry about that. I was trying to say the coxph() gave a wired hazard ratio in my simulation case. And I couldn't find the reason. I didn't mean there is any problem with coxph(). Already corrected. Sorry about that, and thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 1):

The hazard ratio doesn't behave the way you expect, unless the proportional hazards assumption is exactly true.

If you compared means or medians, you would find that the differences in means or differences in medians behaved the way you expect, because these are differences of summary statistics for single groups. You don't necessarily get that behaviour for statistics that aren't differences of one-sample summary statistics.

Things can get worse: if the proportional hazards assumption is far enough from being true it's even possible than $HR_{AB}$ and $HR_{BC}$ and $HR_{CA}$ fitted in separate models are **all less than 1**.